# why do we have to slice the data while showing in frontend

Tags: html, node.js, rendering

```
products = [ { product: 'dd' } ]
console.log(products);
output 
[ { product: 'dd' } ]

 res.render('shop'{prods:products,docTitle:'shop'});
```

shop.pug

```
i am rendering it is working fine
    h1.product__title #{prods.product} // output dd



 h1.product__title #{prods} // object object output
```

But why do i get object insted of [ { product: 'dd' } ] when i run

how webbrowser reads the data

Answer (score 0):

`[object Object]` is returned because it's what `Object.prototype.toString()` returns by default.

You should serialize `prods` object to JSON in order to get its textual representation.

Since you use `pug` as the the template engine the following should work:

```
h1.product__title !{JSON.stringify(prods)}
```